# Prove that the equation of the tangent at P is $ \frac {xx_1}{a^2} - \frac {yy_1}{b^2} = 1 $ (Hyperbolas)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

> > Question: Point P ($x_1 , y_1$) is on the hyperbola $\frac {x^2}{a^2}$ - $\frac {y^2}{b^2}$ = 1
> >
> > Prove that the equation of the tangent at P is
> >
> > $$ \frac {xx_1}{a^2} - \frac {yy_1}{b^2} = 1 $$

---

What I have attempted:

Equation of a tangent is:

$$ (y-y_0) = m(x-x_0) $$

In this case we have $x_0 = x_1$ and $y_0 = y_1$ Now we need to find $m$ so I am going to implicitly differentiate the equation of the hyperbola

$$ \frac {x^2}{a^2} - \frac {y^2}{b^2} = 1 $$

$$ \frac {2x}{a^2} - \frac {2y}{b^2} (\frac {dy}{dx})= 1 $$

$$ \frac {dy}{dx}= \frac {xb^2}{ya^2}$$

at $x = x_1$ and $y = y_1$

$$ \frac {dy}{dx}= \frac {x_1b^2}{y_1a^2}$$

With $ (y-y_0) = m(x-x_0) $

$$ (y-y_1) = \frac {x_1b^2}{y_1a^2}(x-x_1) $$

$$ (y-y_1) = \frac {xx_1b^2}{y_1a^2} -  \frac {x_1^2b^2}{y_1a^2} $$

$$ (y-y_1) = \frac {xx_1b^2 - x_1^2b^2 }{y_1a^2}  $$

$$ yy_1a^2 - y_1^2a^2 = xx_1b^2 - x_1^2b^2 $$

$$ \frac{yy_1}{b^2} -\frac{y_1^2}{b^2}  = \frac{xx_1}{a^2}  - \frac{x_1^2}{a^2}$$

$$ \frac{x_1^2}{a^2} -\frac{y_1^2}{b^2} = \frac{xx_1}{a^2} - \frac{yy_1}{b^2} $$

Now I am stuck I am trying to get rid of

$ \frac{x_1^2}{b^2} -\frac{y_1^2}{b^2} $ and try to make that equal to $1$ and prove the statement but the equation of the hyperbola is given $\frac {x^2}{a^2}$ - $\frac {y^2}{b^2}$ = 1...

Comment: (in the second-last line of equations) Why is the denominator of the $x_1^2$ term $b^2$?

Comment: @πr8 my bad typo!

Comment: Then you're done! $\frac{x_1^2}{a^2} -\frac{y_1^2}{b^2} = 1$ because $(x_1,y_1)$ lies on the given hyperbola, $\frac{x^2}{a^2} -\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(x_1,y_1)$ lie on hyperbola, they satisfy the equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$

$$ \frac{x_1^2}{a^2}-\frac{y_1^2}{b^2} = 1$$

$$\implies\frac{xx_1}{a^2} - \frac{yy_1}{b^2} = 1$$

Comment: I don't understand why this is the case... so if I had any point lets say (2,4) they satisfy the equation and would equal 1?

Comment: @dydxx Yes. When a point lies on a curve, it satisfies its equation. (or vice versa)

Comment: In fact, this trick is not easily accepted at once.  This work implies existence of intersection only.  For tangency, we need to test the implicit differentials: $\frac{2x\, dx}{a^{2}}-\frac{2y\, dy}{b^{2}}=0$.  Now you can verify the tangency by comparing the coefficients.